# Integral with moving average

Tags: integration

[image]

Hi everyone,

My buddies and I are stuck on this question.  What is this question even asking for? We know it has to do something with taking the integral over different sections. But how do we go about coming up with a solution to this question?

Comment: The question is asking for a sketch of the function $f(t)$ and its averaged version. You can see the moving average really just as a mean calculated from $t-L$ to $t$ where $L$ is the length of the averaging window and $t$ is current time. It's like a low-pass filter if you're familiar with electronics. Any sharp spikes (high frequency variations) in your data (i.e. the function $f(t)$) will be averaged out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are given a formula and specific values for $L$ and $f(t)$, so plug them in.$$\overline{f}(t)=\frac 1L\int_{t-L}^tf(\tau)\ d\tau=\frac 11\int_{t-1}^t(1-|\tau|)\ d\tau$$  Can you do this integral?  For ranges of $t$ such that $0 \in [t-1,t]$ it may help to split it into two parts so you know what to do with the absolute value signs in each part.